# Orphaned Pages in NextJS using <Link>

Tags: next.js, next-router, sem

A recent SEM Rush report indicated thousands of orphaned pages on this site. Much must be due to the fact that we use infinite scroll, no static pagination or index page. However, I would like to know if it is possible that the robots do not consider the link when the `<Link>` component of the `next/router` is used without the `<a>` as a child. I noticed that throughout the site, the `<a>` tag is not being used within the `<Link>`, could this be a cause?

Several pages that appear in the report have a link on the home page, for example, but without the `<a>` tag.